# Weight issue in opencart

Tags: opencart

I create new product in opencart and select weight in grams for product but in store front cart is showing kilogram.

Due to your quality problem i am writing again.

I create new product in opencart and select weight in grams for product but in store front cart is showing kilogram.

Answer (score 1):

Because in `System >> Settings >> local` **Weight Class** is set as `kilogram` and that unit will be shown in cart.

The unit (g) you set in individual product is just used so that you can enter weight in units you know at that time and you don't have to do conversion yourself but cart will always show weight in a unit which is saved in overall settings by doing appropriate conversions

Comment: so there is anyone that gram product show g ?...i mean after change any coding ?

Comment: @Waqas cart page shows total weight so it can show it only one unit, so if you want to show gram just change settings to gram. consider a case when one product is in gram and other is no kilogram, to avoid these type of conflict there must be a single unit in settings

Comment: @Waqas Just go to Your admin, system, settings, edit the current store, switch to Local tab and set the unit **gram** for the weight class. Then hit **Save**. Done.